# Arguments should have same length error in R

Tags: r, data-science, lapply, sentiment-analysis, tapply

I'm trying to create a key-value store with the key being entities and the value being the average sentiment score of the entity in news articles.

I have a dataframe containing news articles and a list of entities called organizations1 identified in those news articles by a classifier. The first row of the organization1 list contains the entities identified in the article on the first row of the news_us dataframe. I'm trying to iterate through the organization list and creating a key-value store with the key being the entity name in the organization1 list and the value being the sentiment score of the news description in which the entity was mentioned.

I can get the sentiment scores for the entity from an article but I wanted to add them together and average the sentiment score.

```
library(syuzhet)
sentiment <- list()
organization1 <- list(NULL, "US", "Bath", "Animal Crossing", "World Health Organization", 
    NULL, c("Microsoft", "Facebook"))
news_us <- structure(list(title = c("Stocks making the biggest moves after hours: Bed Bath & Beyond, JC Penney, United Airlines and more - CNBC", 
"Los Angeles mayor says 'very difficult to see' large gatherings like concerts and sporting events until 2021 - CNN", 
"Bed Bath & Beyond shares rise as earnings top estimates, retailer plans to maintain some key investments - CNBC", 
"6 weeks with Animal Crossing: New Horizons reveals many frustrations - VentureBeat", 
"Timeline: How Trump And WHO Reacted At Key Moments During The Coronavirus Crisis : Goats and Soda - NPR", 
"Michigan protesters turn out against Whitmer’s strict stay-at-home order - POLITICO"
), description = c("Check out the companies making headlines after the bell.", 
"Los Angeles Mayor Eric Garcetti said Wednesday large gatherings like sporting events or concerts may not resume in the city before 2021 as the US grapples with mitigating the novel coronavirus pandemic.", 
"Bed Bath & Beyond said that its results in 2020 \"will be unfavorably impacted\" by the crisis, and so it will not be offering a first-quarter nor full-year outlook.", 
"Six weeks with Animal Crossing: New Horizons has helped to illuminate some of the game's shortcomings that weren't obvious in our first review.", 
"How did the president respond to key moments during the pandemic? And how did representatives of the World Health Organization respond during the same period?", 
"Many demonstrators, some waving Trump campaign flags, ignored organizers‘ pleas to stay in their cars and flooded the streets of Lansing, the state capital."
), name = c("CNBC", "CNN", "CNBC", "Venturebeat.com", "Npr.org", 
"Politico")), na.action = structure(c(`35` = 35L, `95` = 95L, 
`137` = 137L, `154` = 154L, `213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `232` = 232L, 
`276` = 276L, `321` = 321L), class = "omit"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

setNames(lapply(news_us$description, get_sentiment), unlist(organization1))

#$US
#[1] 0

#$Bath
#[1] -0.4

#$`Animal Crossing`
#[1] -0.1

#$`World Health Organization`
#[1] 1.1

#$Microsoft
#[1] -0.6

#$Facebook
#[1] -1.9

tapply(sapply(news_us$description, get_sentiment), unlist(organization1), mean) #this line throws the error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to arise from the use of 'unlist'. Avoid this, as it drops the NULL values and concatenates list entries with multiple values.
Your `organization1` list has 7 entries (two of which are NULL and one is length = 2). You should have 6 entries if this is to match the `news_us` data.frame - so something is out of sync there.

Let's assume the first 6 entries in `organization1` are correct; I would bind them to your data.frame to avoid further 'sync errors':

`news_us$organization1 = organization1[1:6]`

Then you need to do the sentiment analysis on each row of the data.frame and bind the results to the `organization1` value/s. The code below might not be the most elegant way to achieve this, but I think it does what you are looking for:

```
results = do.call("rbind", apply(news_us, 1, function(item){
    if(!is.null(item$organization1[[1]])) cbind(item$organization1, get_sentiment(item$description))
}))
```

This code drops any rows where there were no detected `organization1` values. It should also duplicate sentiment scores in the case of more than one `organization1` being detected. The results will look like this (which I believe is your goal):

```
     [,1]                        [,2]  
[1,] "US"                        "-0.4"
[2,] "Bath"                      "-0.1"
[3,] "Animal Crossing"           "1.1" 
[4,] "World Health Organization" "-0.6"
```

The mean scores for each organization can then be collapsed using `by`, `aggregate` or similar.

[Edit: Examples of `by` and `aggregate`]

```
by(as.numeric(results[, 2]), results$V1, mean)
```

```
aggregate(as.numeric(results[, 2]), list(results$V1), mean)
```

Comment: How can the mean scores for each organization be calculated? I see you've mentioned by or aggregate but I'm unsure of how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer to show how `by` or `aggregate` would be used. Obviously there are no duplicates in this small example dataset, so the means are the same as the raw values - but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: `aggregate(as.numeric(results[, 2]), list(results[, 1]), mean)` seemed to work for me, thanks so much for all the help!